# React closure works with missing dependency

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand more about the dependency requirements when using a React hook. Using `useMemo` as an example, I can increment the counter and the value of `dog` is rendered as the same value as `count`. This is odd to me because `foo` is not referenced as a dependency and from my understanding, this closure should be stale.

From the React docs in regards to `useMemo`:

> every value referenced inside the function should also appear in the dependencies array

It doesn't seem like this^ is a requirement. If someone could help me better understand how the closure works in this particular case, I'd appreciate it.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const foo = useMemo(() => count, [count]);
  const dog = useMemo(() => foo, [count]); // incrementing count updates this value

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {dog}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>You clicked {count} times!</h2>

      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Decrement</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way you've set things up, it happens to be that every time `count` changes, `foo` also changes. So even though you're checking the wrong variable, there's a 1:1 correspondance between times you want the memoization to break and times it actually breaks.

You shouldn't rely on this though. It is rare that things will be as simple as your example, and so you will easily make mistakes. To reliably get it to work, you should populate the dependency array with the values you actually depend on, not things which are merely synchronized with the values you depend on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Are you able to drill into this a little bit more.. "there's a 1:1 correspondence between times you want the memoization to break and times it actually breaks". 

I understand what should be done in practice and what React conceptually expects. I guess I am just wondering why it works.

Comment: The dependency array says "Compare each of these values to their previous ones using ===, and if any changed, break the memoization and recompute". Let's say that on render number 7, it sees that `count` did not change. Therefore it skips recomputing. Coincidentally, `foo` didn't change either, so we don't mind. Then on render number 8, it sees that `count` **did** change. Therefore, it breaks the memoization and recomputes. Coincidentally, `foo` also changed at this time, so it's a good thing we are recomputing. So it's recomputing when it needs to, but only because it got lucky.

Comment: That makes sense to me. My perception was that the values referenced inside React hooks were the result of what was passed in as dependencies but it's really the result of what their state is at the point where the memoization breaks.